# Pure CSS infinite looping slider animation jump issue

Tags: html, css, animation, slider, css-animations

I have created an infinite CSS slider for this site:
[My Website](http://www.highspiritdrinks.com/test/)

The animation is jittering and there is a jump at the end the loop.

Now I understand that I need to time the animation so that it completes one full loop and use the part of the image that is duplicated to create the illusion that it has looped.

I used this site to get the code to help me: [CSS animated slideshow Code](https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/)

- My first question is what does this line of code do and is it
  relataed the percentage of the image that is repeated for the looping
  effect:

  left: -200%;
- My second questions is what is the best way to ensure a smooth,
  looping animation without any jerking/jumpiness

?